# 'image' is a required property error from openai create image edit api while there's image blob in form data

Tags: reactjs, openai-api, rtk-query

I'm requesting an image edit from Openai API using RTK Queries but it keep returning error 400: 'image' is a required property while theres image sent.
My code

```
const handleEdit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    const base64String = `data:image/png;base64,${props.props}`; // Base64 string
    const binaryString = atob(base64String.split(",")[1]); // Binary data string
    const blob = new Blob([binaryString], { type: "image/png" }); // Create a BLOB object
    formData.append("image", blob);
    formData.append("prompt", "big hats");
    formData.append("size", "512x512");
    
    formData.append("n", 1);

    editImg(formData).then((res) => console.log(res));
  };
```

RTK Query

```
    editImg: builder.mutation({
      query(body) {
        return {
          url: `images/edits`,
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
          body,
          formData: true,
        };
      },
    }),
```

Request described on console (i changed image to a string for easier view, it's supposed to be a blob)

```
XHRPOST
https://api.openai.com/v1/images/edits
[HTTP/2 400 Bad Request 284ms]

1

-----------------------------388091800212596833946822683

2

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="prompt"

3

​

4

big hats

5

-----------------------------388091800212596833946822683

6

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="size"

7

​

8

512x512

9

-----------------------------388091800212596833946822683

10

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

11

​

12

aa.png

13

-----------------------------388091800212596833946822683

14

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="n"

15

​

16

1

17

-----------------------------388091800212596833946822683--

18

​
```

Response

```
XHRPOST
https://api.openai.com/v1/images/edits
[HTTP/2 400 Bad Request 284ms]

1

{

2

  "error": {

3

    "code": null,

4

    "message": "'image' is a required property",

5

    "param": null,

6

    "type": "invalid_request_error"

7

  }

8

}

9

​
```

Tried changing image to base 64, random string, removing...

I will gladly provide more info. Would really appreciate your help

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you find the solution?